# Gulp - Replace Text

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp task that looks like this:

```
gulp.task('rename-package', function() {
  gulp.src('package.json')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('packaged')
  ;
});
```

This task takes the "package.json" file and copies it to the "packaged" directory. "package.json" has a line that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "processData ./temp/data.json"
},
```

I need to replace the above with the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "processData ./data.json"
},
```

Essentially, it's just changing the path referenced. Still, I need to make this conversion in Gulp. My question is, is there a way to do that? If so, how?

Thank you,
Chad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin to replace a string within a file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace